# Regex to find all URLs that contains "logo" ending with image extension

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find logos on websites.

XPath (`//img[contains(@src,"logo")]/@src`) works if the logo is inside  but there are websites that have their logo defined in style:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         someclass {
            background-image: url("/css/images/logo2.jpg");"
            background-color: #cccccc;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
   </body>
<html>
```

So I'm trying to build a regex for such cases:

```
[\"\']([\a-zA-Z0-9-_]*logo[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg)).*?"
```

This, for example, is capturing `"/e/logo_adsada.jpg?size=400"` but also next characters.

Here is the example:

https://regex101.com/r/rV3oP8/160

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Don't escape the `\a` in the character class

Comment: `<div>the image can be found at "/e/logo.jpg"</div>` <-- You'll match this but shouldn't. Good luck parsing HTML/CSS with RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is greediness. This is usually a flag in regex engines. On the website you posted you could activate the "**U**ngreedy" flag.

Quoting a quote from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions#:%7E:text=The%20standard%20quantifiers%20in%20regular,tries%20the%20minimal%20match%20first.&text=Greedy%20matching.), who is quoting [Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

> The standard quantifiers in regular expressions are greedy, meaning
> they match as much as they can, only giving back as necessary to match
> the remainder of the regex.
>
> By using a lazy quantifier, the expression tries the minimal match
> first.

Answer (score 0):

Below regex will help

```regex
["']([\a-zA-Z0-9-_]*?logo[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*?\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg)).*?['"]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rYfU0T/1)